# using htaccess on Coldfusion server

Tags: .htaccess, coldfusion

I have a .cfm based site and I want anyone who types in www.domain.com/blog to be redirected to http://blog.domain.com

So I created a .htaccess file and uploaded it to the root directory of the site.
The contents of the htaccess file are below. My issue is that it does not seem to work (nothing happens when I go to www.domain.com/blog
Obviously I have the real domain name instead of "domain.com" in my code. however is there anything more I need to do to get this to work?

```
 RewriteEngine On
 Redirect 301 /blog http://blog.domain.com
```

Comment: `redirect` is not part of mod_rewrite, so there's no point in enabling mod_rewrite in the first place. and did you enable .htaccess in your server config?

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Try `RewriteRule /blog http://blog.domain.com [R=301]`